# Is it possible to add a trigger to watch when user starts following a topic

Tags: trigger

Im looking to track when users follow topics but it seems like you cant add a trigger to the EntitySubscription object which is what you'd need to track

Any other ways to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question made me curious. It's clear from the documentation that EntitySubscription doesn't support triggers. The relevant schema drawing of the chatter related objects with User is shown below:

[image: Chatter Feed Objects Schema]

EntitySubscription supports the following calls:

`create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query() and retrieve().`

There were a few notes in the usage that particularly caught my attention which are as follows:

> - If you deactivate a user, any EntitySubscription where the user is associated with the ParentId or SubscriberId field, meaning all
>     subscriptions both to and from the user, are soft deleted. If the user is reactivated, the subscriptions are restored. However, if you deactivate multiple users at once and these users follow each other, their subscriptions are hard deleted. In this case, the user-to-user EntitySubscription is deleted twice (double deleted). Such subscriptions can’t be restored upon user reactivation.
> - A query must include a LIMIT clause and the limit can’t exceed 1000.
> - A query using a WHERE clause can only filter by fields on the EntitySubscription object.
> - If user sharing is enabled and the querying user is not an administrator, a SOQL query must be constrained either by the ParentId or SubscriberId. Otherwise, the query behavior at run time is undefined, meaning the result set can be incomplete or inconsistent from invocation to invocation. For an unconstrained query, the sharing check limits imposed on a non-adminstrative user are likely to be exceeded before the query completes, because access checks are run against both parent and subject, for each row of the result set. We recommend using the Chatter REST API to query EntitySubscription data instead of running a SOQL query.

By now you're probably wondering where in the world I'm headed with all of this. Not to worry, I'm nearly there.

Clearly, `EntitySubscription` can be queried. All changes that have occurred since the last time you ran a query, can also be queried, provided the number of updates doesn't exceed 1000 for the query conditions. The conditions would need to be limited to the `subscriberIds` (Users) and/or the `ParentIds` (Topics) that you want to include in your query along with the `NetworkId` if a Community is involved.

This suggests to me that one way of collecting your data would be to write a schedulable class that runs at regular intervals to query the `EntitySubscription` object. The class would then collect subscription data at regular intervals on the topics you want to track.

How often to schedule it to run would be dependent on the size of your organization and the number of topics that you're tracking. A schedulable would process the data you collect through its query in the same manner a trigger would, just asynchronously as opposed to it happening in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response.  While it wasnt the answer i was hoping for this is clearly the best way to go so im gonna setup a some scheduled apex to watch for the change.  Thanks again!